# How do I create a RemoveAll method in C#?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

It should remove all occurrences of a value from the Stack.
This is my code but it somehow has a problem with my while statement.

At some test cases, it highlights the while statement and throw me an unhandled exception "System.NullReferenceException"

```
public bool RemoveAll(T value)
{
    if (Count == 0)
        return false;

    if (Count == 1)
    {
        if (mTop.Data.Equals(value))
        {
            mTop = mTop.Next;
            return true;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        OurListNode<T> pTmp = mTop;
        while (pTmp.Next != null)
        {
            if (pTmp.Next.Data.Equals(value))
            {
                pTmp.Next = pTmp.Next.Next;
            }
            pTmp = pTmp.Next;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: at some test cases, it highlights the while statement and give me a "System.NullReferenceException"

Answer (score 1):

In the line `pTmp.Next = pTmp.Next.Next;` the assigned value of `pTmp.Next.Next` might be `null`, so in `while (pTmp.Next != null)` `pTmp` is `null` and doesn't have `Next`. Check it for `null` as well

```
while (pTmp != null && pTmp.Next != null)
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!! I tried it and it wont throw an error anymore.. but it stills doesn't work the same way I wanted it to because the output of my test code is:
2:1:3:2:3:2:1:2

RemoveAll #1
2:3:2:3:2:2

RemoveAll #3
2:2:2:2

RemoveAll #2
2:2

Comment: @Angela You are missing the first and last items, instead of  `pTmp.Next` use just `pTmp` in the `else` block.